# Manga about a man who is reincarnated after he dies of old age and given an overpowered wooden sword by a god

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

This story begins with our protagonist waking up in what I remember as a forest after being reincarnated by a god. However, this man seems to have amnesia for parts of his past life. I believe he died from old age.

After he gets reincarnated, he finds he has several skills one of which is an item storage. In this item storage he has a couple items the only one I can remember would be a wooden sword. It seems this guy's sword skills is almost maxed if not already maxed because of his previous life achievements he also is very proficient is several other skills I think like CQC. The reason this wooden sword is overpowered is because it is unbreakable which was granted by the god.

Later in the manga the god sends an angel to retrieve this wooden sword from him because of it being too powerful for the world he is in. The angel disguises herself as a merchant and not knowing the wooden sword is super powerful trades his wooden sword for a real sword which I believe is a katana. However, once the angel gets back to heaven and tells the god that she has finally gotten this broken item back she finds out that the god transferred the power from the wooden sword to the one he just bought.

That is all I remember about the story. I read this novel online a couple months to a year ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure this is ***[[New Life+] Young Again in Another World](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=137168)***

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/new-life-young-again-in-another-world):

> When death tapped Renya Kunugi on the shoulder, he smiled and went willingly. After enjoying a nice, long life of 94 years, he was looking forward to shutting his eyes for the last time. He was, therefore, understandably upset when he woke up again in an empty space, devoid of memories, with a young girl in a tunic rambling on and on about how she's God. So, he did what any reasonable person would have done under those circumstances: he sent the girl flying with a kick to the face. It turned out that the girl was indeed God, and she was in a pinch. She urgently needed someone to do some interdimensional Resource smuggling, and Renya fit the bill. His mission: cross the boundary into another world, then chill for a few decades. God would handle the rest. The next thing he knew, he was standing in a foreign land, younger, stronger, and more clueless than ever. Will he survive this world? And more importantly, will the world survive him?

A man dies at the age of 94 and a god reincarnates him as a young man in another world. In this new world, he has an inventory system and a shinai (a bamboo sword used in kendo) which, unbeknownst to him, has the attribute of indestructibility. He later trades the shinai for a katana, and the god transfers the indestructibility attribute from the former to the latter.

[image]

[image]